# Changed a textarea to a RTE textarea, now not working in safecracker

Tags: safecracker, custom-fields

I had a custom field in a channel that was a standard text area. This was also included within a safecracker form. I recently changed the field to a RTE text area field, and all my existing entries updated nicely.

However I have this field in a safecracker form like so

```
<textarea rows="8" class="span16" name="my_custom_field" id="my_custom_field" value="my_custom_field">{my_custom_field}</textarea>
```

and now when an entry is submitted via the safecracker form, it throws up an error

with `Message: Undefined property: EE::$rte_lib`

So I am assuming this is because i have change this field. Can I easily change the safecracker form to work with this field?

**Should add:**
I'm not worried about the RTE features being available on the front end, just in the CP. Not sure if this helps things!

Comment: Could you let ExpressionEngine build its own form field and let us know if this resolves it at all?

`{field:my_custom_field}`

Comment: I tried that, and when I use the standard '{field:my_custom_field}' it produces a standard textarea, but when I attempt to submit the form, it throws up the same

    Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: EE::$rte_lib

Filename: rte/ft.rte.php

Line Number: 38

Comment: Probably best you report this as a bug to EllisLab. Regardless of your settings, there is no reason EE should be spewing PHP errors.

Comment: Before reporting, please check my answer below and make sure all 3 components of the addon are correctly installed.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the RTE Module, Field Type and Extension installed. You might be missing one of these.

Comment: Just wanted to support this answer - the error message is being thrown by the RTE module when the field data is being validated (before saving). Specifically the error is happening because EE can't find the RTE library. Suggests that the RTE module is not installed properly or broken in some way.

Comment: Yep, all installed, module, extension & fieldtype. Works fine in cp, but above error in safecracker.

Comment: Sounds like a bug then and best to contact EllisLab directly.